# Obtaining %appdata% from windows service [C++]

Tags: c++, wmi, user-profile, appdata

As in the topic - is there any way to get currently logged user appdata environment variable?

In an application there is no problem to do that with SHGetFolderPath() or simply getenv("appdata") but in service these methods doesn't work. It runs as "SYSTEM" account.

I think that should be a way to obtain %appdata% using WMI but I'm not sure about that.

%userprofile% is the second point of interest by I handle it when I will get %appdata%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a service viewpoint, there's no such thing as "the" currently logged-on user. There might be zero, one or more. Furthermore, it generally indicates a design error if your service needs it. What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @sephirot There may not be a "currently logged in user". There may also be more than one "currently logged in user". As MSalters said, there's probably a design problem here. What's the underlying problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @sephirot: that's something you shouldn't do from a service. Write a regular application instead.